# Android Custom autocompletetextview freezes on backspace click

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am using a autocompletetextview with custom adapter in android. it works fine. But when i click backspace to clear selected item from autocomplete textview it freezes, or there is a delay in deleting. How can i overcome this ? My filter codes are given below

```
 @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {
            suggestions.clear();
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            for (Names people : tempItems) {


  if(people.getName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString()
  .toLowerCase())) {
                    suggestions.add(people);
                }
            }
       //     FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults 
  results) {
        List<Names> filterList = (ArrayList<Names>) results.values;
        if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
            clear();
            for (Names people : filterList) {
                add(people);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

What am i doing wrong ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Modify you filter according to the below code. You are notifying the adapter inside the loop, it should be notified once the whole list is added into the other list i.e. outside the loop.

**// This is my whole adapter and works like a charm and about the updation on the UI thread, yes I am notifying the adapter on the UI thread.**

```
   public class SuburbSuggestionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

    protected static final String TAG = "SuggestionAdapter";
    private List<String> suggestions;
    private Context context;
    private List<String> SuburbList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SuburbSuggestionsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
        suggestions = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (null != suggestions ? suggestions.size() : 0);
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int index) {
        return suggestions.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter myFilter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();

                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)){
                    WebServiceHandler.hitFetchSuburbList(context, constraint.toString(), new CallbackRest() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDone(String response) {
                            if(SuburbList.size()!=0){
                                SuburbList.clear();
                            }
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                                    SuburbList.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    // A class that queries a web API, parses the data and
                    // returns an ArrayList<GoEuroGetSet>
                    List<String> new_suggestions = SuburbList;
                    suggestions.clear();
                    for (int i=0;i<new_suggestions.size();i++) {
                        suggestions.add(new_suggestions.get(i));
                    }

                    // Now assign the values and count to the FilterResults
                    filterResults.values = suggestions;
                    filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint,   FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return myFilter;
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. what is `SuburbList`. 2. you does nothing with `resutls.values` inside `publishResults` ... it is useless

Comment: I have done the same thing you doing inside the publishResults in the getFilter() method. Please try and read the whole code before marking it as negative.

Comment: *I have done the same thing you doing* **NOT ME**  *inside the publishResults in the getFilter() method* **terrible idea, it should be done back on UI thread...** *Please try and read the whole code before marking it as negative.* **please read the comment ... it cannot be used becuase there is no `SuburbList` inside original code.**

Comment: I have provided you with my code implementation which I have used. You just have to analyse the code and make modification to your code. Talking about the **terrible idea thing**, I mean who notifies the adapter after adding every item to the list in a  loop, **I mean really!**

Comment: If you have a better answer, why not post here... I mean this is the place to give something back to the community right rather than just trolling people and fooling around!

Comment: Now it's even worst `performFiltering` is done on non UI thread, you call `WebServiceHandler.hitFetchSuburbList` which seems to be async inside ... which means that app hits `publishResults` before `onDone` ... that's how bad programs are made

Comment: Then why don't you share your **BETTER SOLUTION** so that every one can learn a thing or two from there.

Comment: Obviously because question is unclear, fx: we dont know what is the base class for custom adapter ... but back for your sample ... there is no need to extend `ArrayAdapter` if you are overriding almost all methods that it provide, obviously BaseAdapter is a better choice

Comment: I have shared with you code of mine and you can provide your solution based on that. Further I don't think the question can be more clearer then this.

Comment: *I have shared with you code* and I said that it is bad code ... I have right to think that way ... *you can provide your solution based on that* no ... I would rather (if I would have time) provide code based on the question ... but it's unclear ... *Further I don't think the question can be more clearer then this* you are wrong, it can be more clear ... It may fx contain whole code of his custom Adapter

Comment: You shared your views of my and the other person's code and nothing else. The person and I have implemented autoCompleteTextView using customAdapter for filtering the data in real time from webService and the code is above for everyone to see and provide a better solution. I have given him my version of the solution. Rather than just marking down the question or the answer, why dont you also share your code, may be some guidance of some sort rather than just views so that others can learn from it.